# Inkscape: The chosen area to be exported is invalid

Tags: inkscape

I make a screenshot, paste it to Inkscape, clip and resize the image to contents. When exporting the image as `.png` I encounter an error:

> The chosen area to be exported is invalid

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controls on the right you have selected a `Custom` area to export but with a height/width of zero (hence it's invalid). So you need to either enter some valid values or select one of the other export area options `Page`, `Drawing` or `Selection`.